# Where can I find a list of possible exceptions that SignInClient.beginSignIn can throw on addOnFailureListener

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

Where can I find a list of possible exceptions that SignInClient.beginSignIn can throw on addOnFailureListener?

```java
SignInClient oneTapClient = Identity.getSignInClient(requireActivity());
oneTapClient.beginSignIn(oneTapSignInRequest).
    addOnSuccessListener(requireActivity(), result -> {
        //...
    }).
    addOnFailureListener(requireActivity(), exception -> {
        //What kind of exception can be caught here?
    });
```

I've found that one possible exception may be `UnsupportedApiCallException` and I've got it handled. There probably are more different types of exceptions and I want to handle them separately.

In the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/identity/SignInClient#beginSignIn(com.google.android.gms.auth.api.identity.BeginSignInRequest)), there is nothing written that could help me.

Comment: Aside from my answer, if you understand Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithGoogle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, all exceptions are present inside [com.google.android.gms.common.api](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/package-summary) package. If you check the [Exceptions](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/package-summary#exceptions) section, you'll see that only 4 exceptions are present:

1. [ApiException](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/ApiException)
2. [AvailabilityException](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/AvailabilityException)
3. [ResolvableApiException](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/ResolvableApiException)
4. [UnsupportedApiCallException](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/UnsupportedApiCallException)

Now, when it comes to the [SignInClient#bbeginSignIn(BeginSignInRequest signInRequest)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/identity/SignInClient#beginSignIn(com.google.android.gms.auth.api.identity.BeginSignInRequest)) method, we can see that it is not declared to throw an exception at all. However, the documentation says:

> If the request cannot be honored, an **exception** will be set on the returned Task. In all other cases, a BeginSignInResult will be returned.

So if there is a failure, [OnFailureListener#onFailure(Exception e)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/OnFailureListener#onFailure(java.lang.Exception)) will be called with an Exception. As you noticed, it can be an [UnsupportedApiCallException](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/UnsupportedApiCallException).

On the other hand, methods like [SignInClient#getPhoneNumberFromIntent(Intent data)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/identity/SignInClient#getPhoneNumberFromIntent(android.content.Intent)) or [SignInClient#getSignInCredentialFromIntent(Intent data)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/identity/SignInClient#getSignInCredentialFromIntent(android.content.Intent)) are explicitly declared that can throw an [ApiException](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/ApiException).